# Verilog- in memory address width and data width

Tags: verilog

I am a beginner of Verilog code. So I have a doubt in address width and data width. By Google, I got address width is a log base 2 of RAM depth and there is no relation between address width and data width. But in a memory, address width is a number of columns. So my doubt is if the data width is larger than the address width means there is any problem occurred? Whether the data can be stored in it.

EX: If I have 16-bit address width and 32-bit data width means what will happen?

Comment: `But in a memory, address width is a number of columns.` Quite incorrect. Address has to select a particular row from the memory, so address width is dependent on depth of memory and data width is dependent on width of memory. Refer to [this image](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/comb14.gif) for some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take this example

`wire [31:0] A[15:0]`

This is generally how we declare memories in verilog. Here the `[31:0]` part can be taken as data width and `[15:0]` can be considered as address width. What this statement actually does is to declare an array with name A (A[0] to a[15]), where each element in the array is of 32 bits.

This simply means that there are 16 address to access, with each address holding 32 bits of data

Comment: yes sir. address width is 16 . But ramdepth is 65536 . it is not mentioned means. then what we will get. I did not get the correct clarification. sir . could u pls tell me?

Comment: hi, sorry for the misleading answer I posted yesterday. A[15:0] creates an array of 16 entries, with each entry containing 32 bits. If A[15:0] isn't mentioned and simply stated as wire[31:0]  A, then A can be considered as a single register with 32 bits of data